# windows phone 7 c# qrcode generation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to write a qr code onto a bitmap image however its seems like SetPixel wont work at all, I don't know whether its a refrence am missing however is the code

```
    WriteableBitmap wbmi = new    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(width, height);

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    int grayValue = bMatrix.Array[y][x] & 0xff;
    if (grayValue == 0)                        
        wbmi.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0,0));                                                    
     else
         wbmi.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
 }
 }
 image1.Source = wbmi;
```

I really need help on this or an equivalent in windows phone 7

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not contain a definition for 'SetPixel' and no extension method 'SetPixel' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)